# Como carregar uma PartialView para criar um comentário

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Estou a trabalhar num projeto para aprender ASP.NET MVC e Razor. Neste momento tenho um modelo de `post` com uma *view*, e uma *view* associada ao **model class** do comentário para criar um novo comentário. Queria saber como devo fazer para colocar a *view* de criação de comentário no final do *post*, e quando submeter como associo o comentário ao post (tenho um variável `PostId` no modelo do comentário para fazer a associação). Inseri manualmente na base de dados alguns comentários e aparecem no sítio certo pois coloquei o `PostId` manualmente, o que não é funcional. Veja a *view* para criar um comentário:

```
    @model shanuMVCUserRoles.CommentSet

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>CommentSet</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MemberID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MemberID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MemberID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O começo está ok, mas será necessário mudar algumas coisas para que faça sentido usar como *PartialView*:

```
@model shanuMVCUserRoles.CommentSet

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Adicione um comentário</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MemberID)    
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PostID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Criar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Note que `PostID` e `MemberID` são `hidden`, e teremos que preenchê-los ao chamar a *Partial*:

```
@Html.Partial("_AdicionarComentario", new CommentSet { PostID = Model.PostID, MemberID = User.Identity.GetUserId() })
```

Isto pode ser carregado na *View* `Details`, ou na *View* que exibe o *Post*. O nome você escolhe.

Ao inserir o comentário, você redireciona a página para o *Post*, e não para o comentário.

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", "Posts", new { PostID = Model.PostID });
```

Comment: @Html.Partial("_AdicionarComentario", new CommentSet { PostID = Model.PostID, MemberID = User.Identity.GetUserId() }) só esta linha já me ajudou mais do que aquilo que encontrei antes, muito boa a resposta!